# Can I repeat a Symfony form in a loop with Twig, or do I have to build it manually?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, formbuilder

I am totally new to Symfony and Twig; just yesterday I was thrown into a legacy project that uses them.

I have a list, produced by a template loop, of `Orders`, each order having a `priority` from 1-5.

I want to add a single dropdown `Select` to each `Order` `row` which submits a form updating that `Order`'s `priority` and refreshes the page.

My question is, can I use Symfony's buildForm in conjunction with this architecture? For now I have the following form constructed manually. Is it even possible to build a series of identical forms like this with Twig?:

```
{% for order in orders %}
<form method="post" action="{{ path('change_priority') }}" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="priority" style="width: 35px; height: 20px;" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="1" {% if order.currentBody.priority == 1 %} selected {% endif %}>1&nbsp;&nbsp;- Low</option>
            <option value="2" {% if order.currentBody.priority == 2 %} selected {% endif %}>2&nbsp;&nbsp;- Normal</option>
            <option value="3" {% if order.currentBody.priority == 3 %} selected {% endif %}>3&nbsp;&nbsp;- High</option>
            <option value="4" {% if order.currentBody.priority == 4 %} selected {% endif %}>4&nbsp;&nbsp;- Critical</option>
            <option value="5" {% if order.currentBody.priority == 5 %} selected {% endif %}>5&nbsp;&nbsp;- No Priority</option>
        </select>
        <input name="order_id" value="{{order.serial}}" type="hidden" />
    </div>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

And here is an image of what I'm after. Changing the priority of any of the `Order` row items changes that `Order`'s priority and then refreshes the page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add them in the form type.
You can not do that in your twig template. 
If you render a field with something like {{ form_row(form.select) }}, it will be flagged as displayed and will not be rendered a second time, even if you call {{ form_row(form.select) }} again.

Comment: Thank you; I've added some code to illustrate how I've decided to build the form manually. I'm going to try to manually access the form data via $username = $request->request->get('_username') or something. If this sounds like a bad idea please let me know.